# Calculating Combinations

Tags: combinations

If I have the following 1000 cars and I know out of those I have:

Colour Red: 300
Engine Size 1.4: 250
Fuel Petrol: 400
Automatic Gears: 600

Firstly how can I calculate how many different combinations there are?
Secondly is there a formula I can use to calculate how many cars would be Red and have 1.4 Engine Petrol?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is an answer to your question . The 4 parameters that you provide ( Colour , Engine, Fuel , Gears ) are mutually independent of each other and have no relation between 
them. That being said no one can identify how many combinations are there as you don't fill the **sample space**.

For your 2nd question, again there is a very easy chance that the 300 cars that have red color 
have engine size (something_else) and fuel (something_else) i.e it is easily possible that 
 all the cars that have engine 1.4 are having fuel as 'diesel' or 'LPG' as you dont give sufficient information.
So in this case no exact answer is possible and only a range for cars that fit you criteria can be given and that would be equal to  **0-250**.